# How can i use explicit transcations in ServiceStack.Ormlite for .Net?

Tags: transactions, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is possible to use an explictit transaction in OrmLite?

For example, in the code below i would like to use the transaction passed as parameter in the query. Is that possible?

```
    public Order QueryOrder(IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OrmTests2"].ConnectionString, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);

        using (IDbConnection dbConn = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            return dbConn.Single<Order>(x => x.CustomerId == 1, [<transaction>]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find info and examples of using [OrmLite's transaction support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#transaction-support) on OrmLite's homepage where you'd just need to call `db.OpenTransaction()` to start an ADO.NET transaction, e.g:

```
using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
using (IDbTransaction dbTrans = db.OpenTransaction())
{
    var customer = db.Single<Order>(x => x.CustomerId == 1);

    dbTrans.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Hi Mythz, in my situation i already have a transaction started, i dont want to open another. I would like to use it. Is that possible?

Comment: @MarcosLommez any command executed within the scope of a transaction should automatically be apart of that transaction.

Comment: Would be so good, if i could pass the an IDbTransaction instance as a parameter to connection´s operations(get, insert, delete, update), just like Dapper does. Do you have plans to implement that feature?

Comment: @MarcosLommez You can [add a feature request for it](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) to see if it's a popular feature request but I'd personally dislike polluting a tonne of API's with this overload.